# What is the magnification of the image produced by a convex objective lens in a refracting telescope

Tags: visible-light, refraction, lenses, telescopes

Let's say a refracting telescope with a convex objective lens and a convex eyepiece is viewing a distant object in space. Will the image produced by the convex objective lens be magnified or reduced? I understand that the eyepiece will magnify the image, but I am not sure whether the objective lens magnifies it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eyepiece and the objective lens work together to produce a coherent image for the eye to view. The magnification that a person sees when viewing an object through a Galilean telescope (which is the kind you have specified) is due to the converging of incident parallel rays through the objective lens, and re-focusing those rays through the eyepiece. I think this image will help you understand the apparatus.
[image]

The image is from Eugene Hecht's Optics, 5th ed, chapter 5. The magnification of the image would then be M=-fo/fe, so it depends on both the objective lens and the eyepiece. In particular their distance from each other.